# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer crash application on release

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have problem with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. I create it like that:

```
self.previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
```

session is my AVCaptureSession object. Its is initialized already. When I pop from view controller my app gets crash. I dont even use this vatiable and I get crash anyway. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1;. self.previewLayer is my class object. I declarate is in my class, then make it property with retain and nonatomic and @synthesize. I use code from [RosyWritter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) and only difference is that I use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. It seems like I heve problem with release this object. Can anybody tell me what I do wrong?

## edit

I finally resolved it. It occurs that I dont unregister videoOut delegate :)

PS: I use automatic reference counting

Comment: What does the stack look like for the crashed thread?

Comment: its look like that: http://postimg.org/image/rig4m7qv5/

Comment: If you move the slider at the bottom of the thread view all the way to the right, it will show *all* the frames in the stack.  That would be more helpful.  However, since the top frame is `obj_msgSend`, I suggest turning on zombies in your build scheme and running with that.  It's likely to give you a more useful message in the debug console.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide some more details about, how you are accessing AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. Please paste crash log if you have.

please try your code simulation with below code of block.

```
if ([self captureManager] == nil) {
        captureManager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];
        captureManager.delegate = self;



        if ([[self captureManager] setupSession] && _captureVideoPreviewLayer == nil) {
            // Create video preview layer and add it to the UI
            _captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[[self captureManager] session]];       



            if ([_captureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported]) {
                [_captureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
            }

            [_captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];


            // Start the session. This is done asychronously since -startRunning doesn't return until the session is running.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];
            });
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. Please check and let me know if we have to go with another solution.